# Comment parler de la personne qui enseigne à l'école primaire ?

Tags: professions, éducation

Comment doit-on parler de la personne qui enseigne dans une école primaire ?

- Professeur (m) / Professeur**e** (f) des écoles
- Maître (m) / Maîtresse (f)
- Enseignant (m) / Enseignante (f)
- Instituteur (m) / Institutrice (f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le terme officiel en 2021 est **professeur des écoles**. Ce terme a officiellement remplacé celui d'instituteurs en 1990. Ce changement d'appellation s'accompagnant d'une modification du recrutement (passage de bac + 2 à bac +3 et c'est désormais bac +5) et de la formation (et du salaire !).

Le corps des instituteurs avaient été créé par la loi du 12 décembre 1792 et le terme est resté largement employé bien après la disparition du corps et l'intégration des anciens instituteurs encore en service dans le corps des professeurs des écoles. On peut éventuellement encore l'entendre mais il est probable qu'il soit de moins en moins employé, ça reste une utilisation de survivance et pas un terme officiel.

Maitre (maitresse) désignait la personne qui enseignait dans les écoles primaires  avant la loi du 12 décembre 1792. Maitre/maitresse n'est pas une fonction ou un métier (comme l'ont été les instituteurs ou le sont les professeurs des écoles) mais le terme est un terme familier encore très employé par les enfants et parfois leurs parents, et les enfants saluent leur enseignant par de sonores « Bonjour maitresse » (« bonjour maitre »).

« Enseignant » est un terme générique qui désigne tout individu qui enseigne, professeur(e) des écoles, professeur(e) du secondaire, maitre/maitresse de conférence, professeur(e) des universités  ...

Comment: Pour les femmes ne doit-on dire professeure (des écoles) ?

Comment: @Dimitris Bien entendu « elle est professeure de écoles ». De même une femme est enseignante.

Answer (score 0):

Ces personnes font partie de la classe générale des enseignants (toutes institutions d'enseignement) . Ils étaient par le passé appelés « instituteurs » ou « maitre d'école » et le restent, mais formellement on les appelle les *professeurs des écoles*. (Wikipédia [instituteur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instituteur), [professeur des écoles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professeur_des_%C3%A9coles)).

**Maître** (féminin : maîtresse), enseignant(e) ou instituteur/institutrice. Ancien titre donné aux instituteurs (maître ou maîtresse d'école). ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C3%AEtre))